# H2 & Ignite query performance

Tags: h2, ignite, query-performance

I am trying to compare performance of application queries on H2 database & Ignite with an Oracle baseline.

I created a test including:

- A set of tables and indexes.
- A data set of random generated data with 50k records per tables.
- A query with 1 INNER & 10 LEFT OUTER joins (query returned around 188k records).

I noticed significant differences in terms of performance.

Running the query, on my machine (i5 dual core, 16Gb RAM):

- Oracle manages to run this query in around 350ms.
- H2 takes 4.5s (regardless of the mode - server & in-memory).
- Ignite takes 9s.

Iterating over the JDBC result set:

- Less than 50ms for H2 in-memory mode
- Around 2s for the H2 server mode
- Around 5s for Oracle
- Around 1s for Ignite

Couple of questions:

- Do these figures make sense? Did I just missed the basics of H2 query optimization?
- Looking at H2 explain plans, what is the exact meaning of scanCount? Is this something constant for a given query & data set or a performance indicator?
- Is there a way to improve H2 performances by tuning indexing or hinting queries?
- How to explain the different between Ignite & H2?
- Is the order of joins important? Asking because on Oracle, having up-to-date statistics, the CBO changes the order of joins. I didn't notice such behavior with H2.

Queries & data I used for this test are available [here](https://github.com/spoutnik-be/h2-ignite-perf.git) on Github.

Thanks,
L.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share some basic facts related to Ignite vs. RDBMS performance benchmarking. Copy-pasting this from a new GridGain doc that will be released this month. Just replace GridGain occurrences with Ignite. Please double-check these principles are followed. Let me know if you don't see a difference.

GridGain and Ignite are frequently compared to relational databases for their SQL capabilities with an expectation that existing SQL queries, created for an RDBMS, will work out of the box and perform faster in GridGain without any changes. Usually, such a faulty assumption is based on the fact that GridGain stores and processes data in-memory. However, it’s not enough just to put data in RAM and expect an order of magnitude performance increase. GridGain as a distributed platform requires extra changes for the sake of performance and below you can see a standard checklist of best practices to consider before you benchmark GridGain against an RDBMS or do any performance testing:

- Ignite/GridGain is optimized for multi-nodes deployments with RAM as
  a primary storage. Don’t try to compare a single-node GridGain
  cluster to a relational database that was optimized for such
  single-node configurations. You should deploy a multi-node GridGain
  cluster with the whole copy of data in RAM.
- Be ready to adjust your data model and existing SQL queries if any.
  Use the affinity collocation concept during the data modelling phase
  for proper data distribution. Remember, it’s not enough just to put
  data in RAM. If your data is properly collocated you can run SQL
  queries with JOINs at massive scale and expect significant
  performance benefits.
- Define secondary indexes and use other standard, and
  GridGain-specific, tuning techniques described below.
- Keep in mind that relational databases leverage local caching
  techniques and, depending on the total data size, an RDBMS can
  complete some queries even faster than GridGain even in a multi-node
  configuration. If your data set is around 10-100GB and an RDBMS has
  enough RAM for caching data locally than it, for instance, can
  outperform a multi-node GridGain cluster because the latter will be
  utilizing the network. Store much more data in GridGain to see the
  difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We are not really trying to compare/achieve similar performances but just trying to understand why the order of magnitude is so big. Are there known issues with so many LEFT OUTER JOIN's?

Comment: Yes, I think it's related to the number of JOINs and the way Ignite joins the data. I see you posted a similar thread on Ignite user list. Let's continue our discussion there: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Ignite-query-performance-with-lots-of-joins-td29323.html